# Случайные имена для персонажа

Tags: c#

Как можно реализовать установку случайных имён для объекта? Например есть массив имен, из них нужно выбрать случайное и присвоить объекту.

```
    class player {
        public int pHealth;
        public int pDamage;
        public string[] pNames = {"Gary", "Peter", "Oleg"};
        public int coins;
        
        public player(int _pHealth, int _pDamage string[] _pNames) {
            pHealth = _pHealth;
            pDamage = _pDamage;
            pNames = _pNames;
        }
    }
 
    static void Main() {
       player player = new player(100, 50, ???);
       Console.WriteLine($"Player name is: {player.pNames}");
    }
```

Comment: Если вы устанавливаете классу значение "имя", то почему вы ожидаете там массив из нескольких имен?

Comment: Вам нужно создать еще один класс фабрики, который будет вам создавать экземпляры класса Player. И вот в этом классе фабрики будет массив из имен из которого будет браться случайным образом имя и создаваться новый экземпляр класса игрока.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot да получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой класс `Random`, он умеет генерить случайные числа. И не используйте венгерскую нотацию из C++, в C# она не имеет никакого смысла. Еще классы принято называть с большой буквы.

```cs
public class Player
{
    private static readonly string[] names = { "Gary", "Peter", "Oleg" };
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public string Name;
    public int Health;
    public int Damage;
    public int Coins;

    public Player(int health, int damage, string name = null)
    {
        Health = health;
        Damage = damage;
        Name = name ?? names[rnd.Next(0, names.Length)]; // если name == null, то сработает генератор
    }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Player player = new Player(100, 50);
        Console.WriteLine($"Player name is: {player.Name}");
        Player player2 = new Player(100, 50, "Alex");
        Console.WriteLine($"Player2 name is: {player2.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если хотите, фабрику покажу, как @Bulson посоветовал, напишите комментарий.

Comment: Как по мне, то совсем зеленым новичкам не нужно лезть в паттерны. А судя с вопроса он вообще зеленый)

Comment: @Andrew любой паттерн можно объяснить как частный случай не влезая вообще в тематику паттернов проектирования, вообще не произнося слова "паттерн".

Comment: ну именно по этому я считаю твой ответ прекрасным - ты не лез в паттерны там, где это не нужно - в ответе новичку)